# JQuery datatable change cell styling according to content without redrawing the whole table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jquery datatable and want to set styling properties (color and background color) according to cell content.
Table is changed very dynamically so I cannot redraw the whole table each time cell content is changed.

Is there a way to do this?

I considered using [column rendering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which is called each time cell is edited and can control data displaying, but I'm not sure this is the best way. in addition render callback gets cell data and not td.

Thanks!!

When calling from rowDrawCallback I used:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

        if (!aData || aData.length == 0) return;

        if(columns.indexOf(INDEX_STAT) >= 0) {
            var state = aData[INDEX_STAT].state;
            var exitCode = aData[INDEX_STAT].exitCode;
            var statIndex = columns.indexOf(INDEX_STAT);
            var statSelector = $('td', nRow).eq(statIndex);

            if (!state)
                log("undef state");

            ResultsModule.updateStatusCellInfo(statSelector, state, exitCode);
        } 
}



var ResultsModule = {
 updateStatusCellInfo: function(selector, state, exitCode){        
    var mapper = ResultsModule.getTestResults(state, exitCode).map;

    var currentStatusString = mapper.status;
    var currentStatusColor = mapper.color;
    var currentStatusBgColor = mapper.bgcolor;

    if (currentStatusString) selector.text(currentStatusString); // updating status as text
    else selector.text(Status.None);
    if (currentStatusColor) selector.css('color',currentStatusColor); // seting status color from mapper
    if (currentStatusBgColor) selector.css('background-color',currentStatusBgColor); // seting status color from mapper
 }
}
```

Comment: Any change in CSS is a redraw.

Comment: Indeed, but I want to avoid redrawing the WHOLE table, and to redraw the specific cell\raw only. Looking for a way to do that.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] because there are specific concerns to every situation and there are a plethora of situations to consider. That is the burden one must bear to post a question.

Comment: I'm not sure about what the example can add. I want to change td css properties according to text content. and want them to be refreshed each time cell is edited. Is there any meaning to the specific css property or the text that is changed? or maybe there are another relevant parameters that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used for this [column.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), that called for the cell before it is drawed.
Maybe it is not function target, but it does the work :).

Getting td can be done by:

```
 var cell = meta.settings.aoData[meta.row].anCells[meta.col];
 var statSelector = $(cell);
 selector.css('color', "");
 selector.css('background-color',"");
```

see [this discussion](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/pull/425) for more information on getting DOM cell from render function.